# Model suddenly 'forgets' all it has learned and stops working at around 110 epochs. NaN loss and 50% accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I've tested over 20 different LSTM network architectures on my dataset and up until now have had no problems whatsoever. But this one model I've tried gets to around the 110th epoch and it suddenly wipes all it has learned and gets NaN loss (See attached screenshot). It happens every time with this model.

The model looks like this:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.kayers.Embedding(numberOfWords, embedding_vector_length, input_length=1000),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.LSTM(256, dropout = 0.6),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.6),
    keras.layers.Dense(128),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001, rho=0.9), loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=700, callbacks=callbacks_list, batch_size=32,
         validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

[image: NaN loss and 50% accuracy after the 110th epoch]

I presume I'm doing something wrong here but I'm not experienced enough to spot it. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't seem to do anything wrong; such crappy behavior is being [continuously reported](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1244) from 2015 until today, with no clear explanation as to why and not a remedy :( Just have a look at the thread in case you find anything useful.

Comment: Oh dear. I'll take a look through the thread and see if there's anything of any use in there. If I manage to fix my problem I'll add an answer to this question about what I changed that resolved it. Thanks @desertnaut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying to use 'relu' on line 6 worked. Not quite sure why as I thought the default would work but oh well:

```
keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')
```